# How do use RxJS with type definitions when using the UMD build?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, umd

For instance :

1. npm i @reactivex/rxjs
2. Create a index.ts file with some function that use RxJs
3. Create an index.html file that reference RxJs UMD build and the
   index.js file  created by the typescript compiler from the index.ts
   one.

here there is a repro : https://github.com/valeriob/Repro_rxjs_typescript
Just run "tsc" and see the compiling error.

How do i get type definitions while editing index.ts in this scenario ?

Following those guidelines https://github.com/zspitz/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/release-2.0/pages/Modules.md#umd-modules 
i was able to make it work by appending "export as namespace rxjs;"
to the file node_modules/rxjs/index.d.ts .

If this should be the solution, should it be done by the library authors ?

Comment: could you add a snippet of code or an explicit question, this one is dangerously close to being closed for being to broad

Comment: Thanks i'll add a repro

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find a workaround, since rxjs does not build with type definitions for its UMD bundle.

First of all, this only works for TS >= 3.5, because you have to switch on [allowUmdGlobalAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowUmdGlobalAccess), or else it will give you this error:

> TS2686: 'rxjs' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a
> module. Consider adding an import instead.

By inspecting the end of the file `node_modules/rxjs/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.js`, you can find that **operators**, **testing**, **ajax**, **webSocket** and **fetch** are like subnamespaces, and everything else is directly under the global `rxjs`:

```js
...

var operators = _operators;
var testing = _testing;
var ajax$1 = _ajax;
var webSocket$1 = _webSocket;
var fetch$1 = _fetch;

exports.operators = operators;
exports.testing = testing;
exports.ajax = ajax$1;
exports.webSocket = webSocket$1;
exports.fetch = fetch$1;
exports.Observable = Observable;
exports.ConnectableObservable = ConnectableObservable;
exports.GroupedObservable = GroupedObservable;
exports.observable = observable;
...
```

So all you have to do is create a .d.ts file like this:

```
export * from 'rxjs'
export * as operators from 'rxjs/operators'
export * as testing from 'rxjs/testing'
export * as ajax from 'rxjs/ajax'
export * as webSocket from 'rxjs/webSocket'
export * as fetch from 'rxjs/fetch'

export as namespace rxjs
```

And now you can use the global `rxjs` in any of you ts files:

```
const { interval } = rxjs
const { filter } = rxjs.operators

interval(500).pipe(
    filter(t => t % 2 === 0)
).subscribe(t => console.log(t))
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think i'm missing something, can you post the tsconfig.json too ? I'm not able to discover it correctly with  "module": "none".

Answer (score 0):

I just have faced the same scenario as you.

First of all, you need to use npm to install rxjs module somewhere on your computer.
in that module, copy the `dist\types` folder into your project. (I named it `rxjs`)

[image].

In that folder, add following lines at the end of the `index.d.ts`:

```
export * as operators from './operators';
export * as ajax from './ajax';
export * as fetch from './fetch';
export * as webSocket from './webSocket';
export * as testing from './testing';
```

Finally, Create the file `global.d.ts` like this:

```
import * as _rxjs from './rxjs';
declare global {
   const rxjs: typeof _rxjs;
}
```

And now you can use the global rxjs!