# load RxJS Typescript typings without importing from CommonJS module?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, electron

I'm creating an Electron app with Typescript support.
I want to use RxJS library in the Renderer process with nodeIntegration set to false.

In the specific window I include the RxJS by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

In the Renderer Process I import specific observables and operators by

```
const { fromEvent } = (window as any).rxjs;//require('rxjs');
const { tap } = (window as any).rxjs.operators;//require("rxjs/operators");
```

Application works correctly but I have no support for types definitions from RxJS. How can I bring the support back? How to import correctly the *.d.ts for RxJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own .d.ts file like this:

```
export * from 'rxjs'
export * as operators from 'rxjs/operators'
export * as testing from 'rxjs/testing'
export * as ajax from 'rxjs/ajax'
export * as webSocket from 'rxjs/webSocket'
export * as fetch from 'rxjs/fetch'

export as namespace rxjs
```

This way was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63768862/616645) answer to a similar question.